# Code runs fine in normal mode but throws exception in debug mode?

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

My code runs fine in normal mode but when i try to run it in debug mode it throws exception, I am trying to create a TF-IDF matrix of genre column in spotify_df. Why is this happening.

**P.S** - genre column of spotify_df contains 1-D list of strings and none of them is empty.

Code:

```
tracks_df = pd.read_csv('tracks_with_genres_v3.csv')

def create_tf_idf(spotify_df):
    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
    tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(spotify_df['genres'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x)))
    genre_df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_matrix.toarray())
    genre_df.columns = ['genre' + "|" + i for i in tfidf.get_feature_names_out()]
    genre_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    return genre_df

def create_feature_set(spotify_df):
    genre_tf_idf = create_tf_idf(spotify_df)

complete_feature_set = create_feature_set(tracks_df)
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\PyCharm\Music_Recommendation_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 516, in __init__
   self.dtype = numeric.dtype(int_type)
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.1.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1491, in _exec
 pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
 File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.1.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
   exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
 File "D:/PyCharm/Music_Recommendation_v2/main.py", line 220, in <module>
   begin("Heartless", "Weeknd")
 File "D:/PyCharm/Music_Recommendation_v2/main.py", line 179, in begin
   complete_feature_set = create_feature_set(tracks_df)
 File "D:/PyCharm/Music_Recommendation_v2/main.py", line 115, in create_feature_set
   genre_tf_idf = create_tf_idf(spotify_df)
 File "D:/PyCharm/Music_Recommendation_v2/main.py", line 95, in create_tf_idf
   tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(spotify_df['genres'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x)))
 File "D:\PyCharm\Music_Recommendation_v2\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 2068, in fit_transform
   X = super().fit_transform(raw_documents)
 File "D:\PyCharm\Music_Recommendation_v2\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1328, in fit_transform
   vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, self.fixed_vocabulary_)
 File "D:\PyCharm\Music_Recommendation_v2\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1222, in _count_vocab
   if indptr[-1] > np.iinfo(np.int32).max:  # = 2**31 - 1
 File "D:\PyCharm\Music_Recommendation_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", 
   line 518, in __init__
   self.dtype = numeric.dtype(type(int_type))
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: double check that both configurations run in the same directory and with the same parameters

Comment: Yes everything is in the same directory.